# How to update message status in ChatList using Quick blox sample?

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

I'm using Quick blox and I downloaded Sample app (https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat) which uses `QMChatViewController`, `QMServices`.

I am using `MessageStatusStringBuilder` class methods in `ChatViewController` to get the status (read/delivered/sent) of message (here this message is not a string it is an instance of `QBChatMessage`) in `ChatViewController` so that I'm showing the message status when ever `QMChatServiceDelegate` calls backs were called.

I have a requirement to show the status(read/delivered/sent) of last message in `DialogsViewController` under each dialog also.
But in `DialogsViewController lastTextMessage` is a string but not a `QBChatMessage` instance.

How to update this message status?

One plus point is I will get callbacks from this `QMChatServiceDelegate` in `DialogsViewController` also, even I can't find the status of message from that.

So how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get the message with the extended request using `date_send` as key and dialog's `lastMessageDate` as value. Then using the instance of the `MessageStatusStringBuilder` class you can get the status of the last message.

```
 QBChatDialog *dialog = ... // your dialog

 QBResponsePage *resPage = [QBResponsePage responsePageWithLimit:1 skip:0];

 NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = @{@"date_sent" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%tu", (NSUInteger)[dialog.lastMessageDate timeIntervalSince1970]]}.mutableCopy;

 [QBRequest messagesWithDialogID:dialog.ID extendedRequest:extendedRequest forPage:resPage successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *messages, QBResponsePage *responcePage) {

                                 NSLog(@"status = %@",[self.stringBuilder statusFromMessage:[messages firstObject]]);

  } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

                                 NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);

  }];
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked for me. Super solution. I really liked the way quick blox implemented but I have to know many things in this I'm implementing one big application using this quick blox So If i have any doubts could you provide support for me sir ?

Comment: Sir I have a requirement, I want to upload profile image for each quick blox user and from there it should be shown to other user who wants to create a chat dialog with the first user I saw sample-content example provided. But here my scenario is different So could you help me please

Comment: In examples they are uploading a file with content type or updating existing file. But how this can be accessed by other users to show image. and even if we provide public as 'yes'. How other user can see the actual users pic. And how the current user has to upload the image and where ? so much confusion sir please help me

Comment: Please, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043763/how-to-upload-the-users-profile-pic-and-how-to-fetch-that-profile-pic-from-anoth/37048260#37048260)

Comment: I have the following doubt could you answer me sir. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043763/how-to-upload-the-users-profile-pic-and-how-to-fetch-that-profile-pic-from-anoth?noredirect=1#comment61637114_37043763

Comment: @IOSGallery look at the question's steps 2 and 3. After updates from my answer this steps will return other users's blobID

Comment: Please can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/40755187/3144836